# UIWebView init giving crash

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am adding UIWebView in a custom view :

```
self.webViewContent = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 110, width: self.frame.size.width - 20, height: self.frame.size.height - 170))
self.webViewContent.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
self.webViewContent.scrollView.bounces = false
self.webViewContent.loadHTMLString(String(format: "<HTML><body style='font-family:OpenSans;'><font size='4'>%@</font></body></HTML>", self.subtab.Content), baseURL: nil)
self.addSubview(self.webViewContent)
```

This gives me a crash on very first line. No console message displayed.

I am declaring web view as follows :

```
var webViewContent: UIWebView!
```

Comment: what the crash'

Comment: Print the (self.frame) and check that your customView is properly initialized or not.

Comment: else add the manual frame width and height and check once

Comment: I am using self.frame.size.width in other subviews as well. No crash there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your self's (CustomView) frame is proper and has some valid value and make sure you do not get a NaN (Not a Number). Try setting the width and height of webView to a static value and see if it crashes.

`self.webViewContent = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 110, width: 200, height: 400))`

There must be a problem with the Custom View's frame or initialization.

Answer (score -1):

try This ,it's working code

```
    self.webViewContent = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 110, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 170))
    self.webViewContent.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    self.webViewContent.scrollView.bounces = false
    self.webViewContent.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.webViewContent.loadHTMLString(String(format: "<html><body style='font-family:OpenSans;'><font size='4'>%@</font></body></html>","Hello World"), baseURL: nil)
    self.view.addSubview(self.webViewContent)
```